# Pytorch get stuck at .to(‘cuda’) or .cuda()

Tags: python, pytorch

I use a docker environment to do some pytorch training work, but frequently get stuck at `.to(‘cuda’)` or `.cuda()` calls. Not know why.
Some system behaviors I notice: The training process has a cpu usage of 100%, and almost 97% are sys time as shown by top 1. I used strace to debug the training process, and also used the /proc file system, found the process keep getting stuck on a poll syscall to a pipe, but I don’t know where the pipe is used in pytorch.

Comment: try move a one small array to cuda, to see is it ok in pytorch and cuda versions. There can be errors what are not reported

Comment: this might indicate an internal GPU error. try resetting the gpu